# GDB set break at incorrect line number when debugging rust (gnu with wasm)

Tags: rust, gdb, substrate

When debugging my big rust project, I face a problem that gdb set break point at incorrect line number.
When I type command to set break point at line 406

```
break <absolute-path-of-my-file>/lib.rs:406
```

it return that break point is created at line 432

```
Breakpoint 2 at 0x5555570b9395: file <absolute-path-of-my-file>/lib.rs, line 432.
```

When I check code at line number 406

```
list <absolute-path-of-my-file>/lib.rs:406
```

It return

```
file: "<absolute-path-of-my-file>/lib.rs", line number: 406, symbol: "???"
```

My question is:

1. Why did it set break at line 432 when I created break at line 406?
2. What does `symbol: "???"` mean in the `list` command return? Thanks for any help!

   PS: Size of binary file (after build without optimization) is 22 GB, larger than my memory (16GB)

Answer (score -1):

@Phùng Hưng Thịnh
When I compile C/C++ program, I used to use following to debug my program.
    g++ -g -Wall source.C
    g++ -g -Wall source.CPP
    g++ -g -Wall source.c
    g++ -g -Wall source.cpp
For debugging I never use the following during compilation:
    -O0
Also I used to use:
    ulimit -c unlimited
to know if program creating any core dump or not?
If we are using dynamic library(.dll/.so/.sl on any platform windows/Linux/AIX/SunOS/HP-UX/OSF1/IRIX/UNIX) and providing break point to a function inside that external library, that may show ??? output.
If you are providing break to a function inside dynamic library the line numbers will provide the line number where you are invoking that external function from external library.
I have given the sample usage of gdb using C C++ program, related compilation options and external dependencies at any operating systems.

I tried following commands at Linux and "CYGWIN_NT" at windows using gdb:
    $ gdb
    (gdb) !ls -d .
    .
    (gdb) quit
Hence can you provide the output for:
    (gdb) !ls "<absolute-path-of-my-file>/lib.rs"
    GNU DEBUGGER(GDB) usage at Rust
    Make sure there is a rust-gdb executable
    Use rust-gdb to debug rustc executable.
    All my previous comments based only on C and C++ programming not at rust-gdb.
Actually I don't have rust/... debugger at my system.
I have only C C++ compiler and debugger here.
Example C Code:
    #include <stdio.h>
    void fun()
    {
        printf( "fun\n");
    }
    int main()
    {
        fun();
        return 0;
    }
Example gdb.exe usage:
    $ gcc.exe  -g -Wall sample.c -o ./a.out
Exampe gdb
    $ gdb.exe -q  ./a.out
    Reading symbols from ./a.out...
    (gdb) break fun
    Breakpoint 1 at 0x100401088: file sample.c, line 4.
    (gdb) run
    Starting program: /cygdrive/c/home/murugesan_openssl/a.out
    [New Thread 6108.0xc88]
    [New Thread 6108.0x2428]
    [New Thread 6108.0x12b8]
    Thread 1 "a.out" hit Breakpoint 1, fun () at sample.c:4
    4        printf( "fun\n");
    (gdb) list
    1    #include <stdio.h>
    2    void fun()
    3    {
    4        printf( "fun\n");
    5    }
    6    int main()
    7    {
    8        fun();
    9        return 0;
    10    }
    (gdb) quit
    A debugging session is active.
        Inferior 1 [process 6108] will be killed.
    Quit anyway? (y or n) y
Example to print code:
$ gdb -q  ./a.out
Reading symbols from ./a.out...
(gdb) break fun
Breakpoint 1 at 0x100401088: file sample.c, line 4.
(gdb) list sample.c:4
1    #include <stdio.h>
2    void fun()
3    {
4        printf( "fun\n");
5    }
6    int main()
7    {
8        fun();
9        return 0;
10    }
(gdb) quit

Comment: I've already disabled all optimization when built code and the file that is provided break point, it does not from outside library, it's in my project code.

Comment: updated my comment at previous post.

Comment: !ls command return nothing, no error, no string result

Comment: Added double quotes for file name. Execute again and let us know the output/error.

Comment: With double quotes or single quotes, the result is still empty. What does that command do?

Comment: Hence I need the related full path of your source file. Instead of displaying /full/path/source.rc you can write related output here: /full/path/source.rc for you to follow your company/IT terms and conditions :)

Comment: thanks for your help, I'll ask IT team about policy and reply next week. Have a nice weekend

Comment: Most welcome and wish you the same :)

Comment: stop using `@author` in the answer. This is a Q&A community, not a forum and all the answers are obviously for answering the OP's question

Comment: I found another project have the same problem (when built from our computer). When I set break point at this line (220)
https://github.com/AcalaNetwork/Acala/blob/master/modules/asset-registry/src/lib.rs#L220
`break <some-path>/Acala/modules/asset-registry/src/lib.rs:220`
It also return that new break is create at different line (235)
`Breakpoint 4 at 0x56105b1190a7: file <some-path>/Acala/modules/asset-registry/src/lib.rs, line 235`